# Google Cloud Messaging, 401 Unauthorized is returned when creating notification key from client

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I followed the example on https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/notifications.html#gen-client trying to create notification key from client.

getAccounts() method did return a valid google account. GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context, accountname, scope) also returns a valid scope string. However the response from the post on https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/googlenotification is 401, and is an html page:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
        <H1>Unauthorized</H1>
        <H2>Error 401</H2>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Logcat shows this: 10-14 13:26:03.911: W/DefaultRequestDirector(22125): Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {}

I double checked the ip filtering, it does show:IPS  Any IP allowed.

Wondering whether this is a known issue or anybody has any idea?

FYI I was able to get the id_token by GoogleAuthUtil.getToken.
this is the http post format I followed:
Http post body:
{
   "operation": "add",
   "notification_key_name": "appUser-Chris",
   "registration_ids": ["4"]
   "id_token": "id_token"
}
headers:
content-type: "application/json"
Header : "project_id": 
Thanks!

Comment: Also I cannot find a forum to report bug to google.

Comment: I've got the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Looks like notification_key_name needs to be the email of the user that gets your id_token, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34298106/3983628).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) with local device groups on Android gives HTTP Error code 401](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34098773/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-with-local-device-groups-on-android-gives-http-erro)